# Apache will not start after IP change

Tags: apache-2.2, centos

I'm running CentOS 5.8 and I had to change my server's IP address. Afterwards, I'm unable start Apache. I am also running virtualmin. The error I'm receiving is: Failed to start service

```
 Starting httpd: httpd: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain   name, using 184.106.146.125 for ServerName
 (99)      
 Cannot assign requested address: make_sock: could not bind to address 50.56.33.100:8080
 no listening sockets available, shutting down
 Unable to open logs
```

I edited my httpd.conf to point to the new IP address like such:

```
 #Listen 12.34.56.78:80
 Listen 184.106.146.125:80
```

And looking at the error it still seems to be referring to the old ip address (50.*).

Comment: Have you tried using grep yet?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's likely another configuration file that is referencing that IP address.  You should use `grep` recursively to find this, for example:

```
grep -ir 50.56.33.100 /etc/httpd
```

Comment: Excellent i think it worked.. It now says: 

     **Starting httpd: httpd: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 184.106.146.125 for ServerName                                [  OK  ]**

Comment: It was referenced in **/etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf:Listen 50.56.33.100:8080**

Comment: I think it's amusing that you put the case insensitive flag up for grep on a search that has only numbers and punctuation. :)

Comment: It's funny, I never use `-i`, unless I'm doing `-r`, and then I always use it (even when it's not needed...). :-)